# Spring mvc 3 Web app design

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-3

In a Spring MVC app, I use a unique controller where users populate info of their session (I'm using @SessionAttributes("Form") ).

```
1) It looks that it works fine, but is it the right way to do things ?
2) I would like to share some data between users, how could I do that ?
```

Comment: There is not enough content here to help SO answer this question.  Please provide a more detailed question.

Comment: Ok but sometime you ask yourself about what you do. So before continuing in a wrong direction I prefer to request opinion of others. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

1. why not, you said it works for you, and is simple and clean. Using one controller is fine until the number of methods aren't too many, after that simple split the class creating a new controller, trying to group Request Mappings logically.
2. save it in a database.

Comment: Thx for first question, but for the second one I don't want to use a DB. Data to be shared are very very small. Is it not possible to share context session ?

Comment: Hmm, if it's not meant to be persisted, you could save your data in a Spring Singleton, but you've to be careful about race conditions.

Comment: OK how coulf I persit data without using db/dao... In a shared session object will be very nice...